# How to Incorporate Code into XAML Property ResizeMode=CanResizeWithGrip or Similar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner, and I acknowledge that there might be better ways to achieve what I'm attempting here, as I'm still learning. I'm trying to set the value of a variable that holds the current width of a grid. Whenever I resize my window, this width changes, and I'm unsure how to access it. My goal is to scale up or down a progress bar when resizing.

Here is the relevant XAML and C# code:

```
<Window x:Class="Lista6.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lista6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainPage" Height="650" Width="1000" 
        Background="#36393F"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Icon="/img/Ikonka2.png"
        WindowStyle="None">
    ///other xaml code

                <ProgressBar  Foreground="White" 
                              Value="50"
                              BorderThickness="0" 
                              Background="Gray"
                              Height="5"
                              Width="{Binding Path=ProgresBarWidth[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
           
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
ObservableCollection<double> width = new ObservableCollection<double> { };

        public ObservableCollection<double> ProgresBarWidth 
        { 
            get 
            {
               return width;
            } 
            set
            { 
                width = value; 
            }
        }

        public AppOperator()
        {
            width.Add(0);
        }
        private void ProgresbarWidthSetter()
        {
            MainPage mp = new MainPage();
            width[0] = mp.MusicBar.Width;
        }
```

Hello, I've bound the progress bar width to the ObservColl property, and I want to update it when resizing the window. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this.
Thanks for any help and wish u all good.

Comment: If you want to bind the Width of the ProgressBar and a FrameworkElement named _MusicBar_, you can directly bind them like `Width="{Binding ElementName=MusicBar, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: Wpf has * for proportional sizing. Look it up. Use grid rows and columns with multiples of * to size them. Put the progress at in one of these rows and it will fill the row.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, i found this comments very helpful. Wish u all good 
Regards Mateusz.